# Javascript check search term against array and return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

Firstly I'm grabbing the search term the user has entered and storing in in the variable 'searchWord' Then defining an array of retailers and setting the length of this array in the variable 'subStringLength'. Now i run w while loop that checks for any of the words in my 'searchWord' and if it finds a match it returns true. The problem is indexOf() only returns a number or boolean. How would I adapt this code so if it matches any of the words with 'searchWord', if returns the value of the word it has matched. I can then take that word and match if with an object key which is used to store voucher codes for that retailer? Any help appreciated, heres how I am doing it so far:

```
const searchWord = $('.form-control').val();
const searchRetailers =['Debenhams','debenhams', 'Argos', 'argos', 'Currys', 'currys', 'PC World', 'Pc World', 'pc World', 'pc world', 'John Lewis', 'john Lewis', 'john lewis','eBay', 'Ebay', 'ebay', 'Amazon', 'amazon'];
let subStringLength = searchRetailers.length;

while(subStringLength--) {
    if (searchWord.indexOf(searchRetailers[subStringLength])!=-1) {
         // show popup 1
    }else {
        // show popup 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what `searchWord` could be!

Comment: so search word could be "Argos television" or "cheap debenhams scarf"

Answer (score 0):

> How would I adapt this code so if it matches any of the words with
>   'searchWord', if returns the value of the word it has matched.

It would be reasonable to stop traversal when matched value found:

```
...
var matched = '';
while (subStringLength--) {
    if (searchWord.indexOf(searchRetailers[subStringLength]) !== -1) {
         matched = searchRetailers[subStringLength]; // <-- capturing matched word
         break;
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```
...
var matched,
    hasMatches = searchRetailers.some(function(w){
         var m = searchWord.indexOf(w) !== -1;
         if (m) matched = w; // <-- capturing matched word
         return m;
    }, matched);

 if (hasMatches) {
    // show popup 1
 } else {
    // show popup 2
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this type of searching because it can usually be handled better by a database which is designed to index/search values like this, however, I'm giving you some rough code, but essentially you can do something like this:

```
const searchWord = $('.form-control').val();
const searchRetailers =['Debenhams','debenhams', 'Argos', 'argos', 'Currys', 'currys', 'PC World', 'Pc World', 'pc World', 'pc world', 'John Lewis', 'john Lewis', 'john lewis','eBay', 'Ebay', 'ebay', 'Amazon', 'amazon'];    

function search(searchWord) {
    searchWord = searchWord.toLowerCase();
    let results = [];
    searchRetailers.forEach(function(el){
        if(el.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchWord) != -1) 
            results.push(el);
    });    
    return results;
}

let matches = search(searchWord);
//Do stuff with matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's answers. I ended up going with the following way as then i didn't need an array and an object storing the code for the retailers, i've used regex to match with the object key value. This way seems to be more efficient than using indexOf() which seemed fairly slow.

```
const searchRetailersCode = {
    'debenhams': {
        'code': 'YH99' 
    },
    'argos': {
        'code': 'HOME25' 
    },
    'currys': {
        'code': '123456' 
    },
    'pc world': {
        'code': '123456' 
    },
    'john lewis': {
        'code': '123456' 
    },
    'ebay': {
        'code': '123456' 
    },
    'amazon': {
        'code': '123456' 
    },
};

const searchWord = $('.form-control').val();

let regexp = new RegExp('(' + Object.keys(searchRetailersCode).join('|') + ')', 'i');
let matches = regexp.exec(searchWord);

if (matches != null && matches.length > 1) {
    let retailer = matches[1].toLowerCase();
    let discountCode = searchRetailersCode[retailer].code; 
}
```